# Groovy iterate a json array list to add new key:value element

Tags: java, json, groovy

I have this json:

```
{
    "books": []
}
```

and I have a loop to add new key:value inside the "books" array list. The result should be:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "bookId": "1",
            "bookName": "name1",
            "bookYear": "2010",
            "bookPrice": "5.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText('''{"books":[]}''')
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("bookId", "bookName", "bookYear", "bookPrice");
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("1", "name", "2010", "5.00");
for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
{
    String key = keys.get(i)
    String value = values.get(i)
    json.books << [key: value]
}

return JsonOutput.toJson(json)
```

but the result is wrong:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "bookId": "1"
        },
        {
            "bookName": "name1"
        },
        {
            "bookYear": "2010"
        },
        {
            "bookPrice": "5.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could you help me with the code?

Thanks

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: post updated adding example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a new json object, and than pust the elements to it:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json_req = '''{
    "books": [
        
    ]
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_req)

json.books << new JsonSlurper().parseText("{}")
println json.books[0]
json.books[0] << [bookPrice:"5.00"] // json.put('sig', '<value>')
json.books[0] << [bookName: "name"] // json.put('sig', '<value>')


println JsonOutput.toJson(json)
```

See https://onecompiler.com/groovy/423ruzp4t